# Jenkins and Exchange Server Integration

Tags: exchange, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am interested in integrating Microsoft Exchange server and Jenkins for email notification. Instead of using SMTP approach, I want to use Exchange server webservices (Administration policies allow connection to exchange server via webservices only). Is there any plug-in which can help achieve that?
I have looked at [Email-ext-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin), but I didn't find an option for Exchange server webservice configuration.

Additionally, If the plugin is available, is there any option of setting trust between Jenkins and Exchange Server instead of configuring mail account user id and password (required as password keep expiring after 45 days and changing that manually in Jenkins will be another management task).

Comment: Additional option, if Jenkins supports that, is to utilize PowerShell. Basically, if Jenkins have some sort of Powershell integration you might want to check into that. Powershell is available in the same manner as EWS.